# what is sensible-mda and do i need it?

Tags: ubuntu, log-files, email-server, sendmail

I'm running Ubuntu Intrepid, and have been seeing the following my logs:

```
Aug 23 16:01:03 wp1 sm-mta[13700]: n7NFJIad013566: Warning: program /usr/sbin/sensible-mda unsafe: No such file or directory
Aug 23 16:01:03 wp1 sm-mta[13700]: n7NFJIad013566: SYSERR(root): Cannot exec /usr/sbin/sensible-mda: No such file or directory
Aug 23 16:01:03 wp1 sm-mta[13700]: n7NFJIad013566: Warning: program /usr/sbin/sensible-mda unsafe: No such file or directory
Aug 23 16:01:03 wp1 sm-mta[13700]: n7NFJIad013566: SYSERR(root): Cannot exec /usr/sbin/sensible-mda: No such file or directory
```

I have tons of these messages now, where I had none before.  Looking it up, it appears Ubuntu has some special sendmail packages that might not have been installed when I installed sendmail.

Do I need "sensible-mda"?  No one should be authenticating nor sending via the server - it's just a default local smtp host that's setup to allow for web forms to post to email, and for the system to send system logs, etc.

Why would these messages just start appearing?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Perhaps you've installed sendmail by using the `sendmail-bin` individual package instead of installing the `sendmail` wrapper package.

Anyway, if you install `sensible-mda` (or the `sendmail` wrapper package), the problem you're seeing should disappear.

Comment: just realized that you WANT this package. otherwise your virtual machine kills itself because the log files take up the whole disk space. true story.

Comment: I totally agree with what @pduersteler says, I also had disk space running low, and checking out the logs I found that not being able to find sensible-mda was filling up all the logs (mail.warn, mail.log and mail.err) that's how I found this post

Answer (score 2):

The sensible-* programs are installed so that other system scripts etc. can rely on a program which provides a certain functionality being in the right location.

`sensible-mda` is a [dependency of sendmail](http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/sendmail), so it should exist on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Also you should seriously consider not running sendmail.

Either `exim4` or `postfix` are much better options for real mail servers, and `ssmtp` and `nullmailer` are much better options for hosts that will only send outbound mail.

As this point the only people who should be running sendmail are those with large old installations or a need for some of the very complex non-SMTP routing that sendmail can do.

Comment: I had not used nullmailer before, but that sounds like exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!